# Laravel Model suddenly uses default table name without plural

Tags: php, laravel

Today when my QA was using our dev project, we suddenly received an error when trying to load a page. This was the error

[image]

As you can see, it's trying to find a table called `courseware` but in our DB it's named as `coursewares`. The weird thing is this has never been an issue before (since last week). But today we came across this issue. The quick fix I had done is to add `protected $table` but we don't want to do this for all 400+ models that we currently have just to avoid this issue in the future.

So, does anyone have any idea what was causing this issue? We never update any laravel frameworks / packages but we did add 2 new packages ([nexmo/laravel](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel) and [jotaelesalinas/laravel-adminless-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-adminless-ldap-auth)) last Friday.

Here's what our composer.json look like :

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "ext-memcached": "3.0.0-dev",
        "artesaos/seotools": "0.13.0",
        "authy/php": "3.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.158",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.6",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.1",
        "buzz/laravel-google-captcha": "^2.1",
        "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "7.*",
        "chumper/zipper": "^1.0",
        "consoletvs/identify": "^1.3",
        "curl/curl": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "facade/ignition": "^1.17",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.1",
        "goodnesskay/laravelpdfviewer": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "^0.12.4",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "joisarjignesh/bigbluebutton": "^1.1",
        "jotaelesalinas/laravel-adminless-ldap-auth": "^0.4.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "mdanter/ecc": "^0.5.2",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.3",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-binary-uuid": "^1.3",
        "spatie/pdf-to-image": "^1.8",
        "spomky-labs/jose": "^7.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.62",
        "xeroapi/xero-php-oauth2": "^2.5",
        "nexmo/laravel": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When removing the two said packages, does it work normally?

Comment: Oh man, you have Laravel 5.5, it was deprecated a long time ago... Still, I am not sure why it is changing the name

Comment: @jrcamatog nope. removing those packages doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: same problem here with laravel9. All of a sudden this started to happen. Any solution?